# Any complex example project for Java desktop-style GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, gwt, swt

I'd like to see how the code is organized and how the various GUI design patterns are applied. Anything Java and in desktop gui style is fine: GWT, Swing, SWT. Thanks.

Comment: @ceejayoz - you mean the Eclipse IDE? Yeah, that's complex enough, maybe too complex for me, :-).

Comment: If you are trying to organize GWT code, please don't refer to a Swing project. Although related, the analogy actually starts hurting after some point. I'd recommend going through MVP pattern, and the recently released MVP architecture notes - http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html

Comment: @sri - thanks. Information in that link is very useful. I am using Vaadin actually, although it uses GWT for rendering, it is a server side framework and IMHO is closer to traditional swing-style programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [tigris.org](http://argouml.tigris.org/images/welcome_screenshot_0_26.png))</sub>

- [OpenProj](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/)

http://openproj.org/themes/bluebreeze/images/OpenProj_big.jpg

- [LimeWire](https://web.archive.org/web/20100326134016/http://www.limewire.com/development)

http://www.blogcdn.com/www.downloadsquad.com/media/2008/12/limewire-1234-4.jpg

Those are some I can remember.

Answer (score 2):

[Azureus](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I was a huge fan of the work done for [Aerith](http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/aerith_source_code_is_available).  It uses Swing and Java 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at projects on [SourceForge.net that is using Java](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/?type_of_search=soft&fq[]=trove:198&sort=num_downloads_week&sortdir=desc&limit=25), there is many. I.e. [JBoss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/), [Hibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/) and [jEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedit/).

Comment: But are JBoss and Hibernate desktop applications?  I thought the first was a Java EE application server and the second a JPA implementation.  jEdit looks useful, though.

Comment: @justkt: Sorry, I didn't see that is was only dektop. Well **jEdit** should be OK.